# I'm confused about the (.) punctuation mark

Tags: word-difference, punctuation, reading-aloud

There are several ways to name a (.) punctuation mark. I can't understand if they anyhow differ?

- Period
- Full stop (also Fullstop)
- Stop
- Point
- Full point
- Dot

I only use the word **"period"**.

Comment: The identical symbol may have different names in different contexts. The  "⋅" character might be an *interpunct* in Latin text but would be a *dot operator* in vector mathematics. A "$" in Canada represents a dollar value, but in Uruguay a peso value. So it is that you do not separate the components of an IP address with *periods*, and you do not end sentences in prose with *points*, and you do not indicate a decimal fraction with *dot*. I would encourage you to check basic references before posting; Wikipedia is usually adequate for initial research.

Comment: @choster Yeh, I know. But somewhere they say **full stop** or **stop** instead of **period** and sometimes people say **dot** instead of **point**. i.e. You should place a full stop before that word and separate the sentence into two. or An examiner says: Her eyes were green [period] She had a beautiful smile [period].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used to mark the end of a sentence or an abbrevation, **period** is the common term in the US and Canada. The rest of the English-speaking world (UK, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, etc.) prefers **full stop**. **Full point** is an archaic synonym of these, but no longer used anywhere.

When it is used with numbers, **point** is used, e.g. 3.6 is pronounced "three point six". **Dot** tends to be used when giving the name of a website, e.g. "amazon dot com".